# Postgres Result Multidimensional from Query

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array

How would one create a Multidimensional Array from a single Postgres Query.

I have 3 tables with the following columns:

- tb_school (id, school_name)
   eg:

  `[
      {id:"1", school_name:"School1"},
      {id:"2", school_name:"School2"}
  ]`
- tb_profile (id, profile_name, school_id)
   eg:

  `[
      {id:"1", profile_name:"John", school_id:"1"},
      {id:"2", profile_name:"Peter", school_id:"1"},
      {id:"3", profile_name:"Sam", school_id:"1"},
      {id:"4", profile_name:"Susan", school_id:"2"},
      {id:"5", profile_name:"Jude", school_id:"2"},
      {id:"6", profile_name:"Kim", school_id:"2"}
  ]`
- tb_article (id, article_name, profile_id)
  eg:

  `[
      {id:"1", article_name:"Headline News", profile_id:"1"},
      {id:"2", article_name:"Sports Recap", profile_id:"2"},
      {id:"3", article_name:"Weather", profile_id:"3"},
      {id:"4", article_name:"Arts", profile_id:"4"},
      {id:"5", article_name:"Other", profile_id:"5"},
      {id:"6", article_name:"Example", profile_id:"6"}
  ]`

I would like the query to return a result lat looks something like this:

```
[
    {school_name:"School1", people:[
        {profile_name:"John", articles:[
            article_name:"Headline News"
        ]},
        {profile_name:"Peter", articles:[
            article_name:"Sports Recap"
        ]},
        {profile_name:"Sam", articles:[
            article_name:"Weather"
        ]},
    ]},
    {school_name:"School2", people:[
        {profile_name:"Susan", articles:[
            article_name:"Arts"
        ]},
        {profile_name:"Jude", articles:[
            article_name:"Other"
        ]},
        {profile_name:"Kim", articles:[
            article_name:"Example"
        ]},
    ]}
]
```

I know one can achieve this by 3 separate select queries in nested for loops. What I want to know is could this be achieved by one single postgres query?

Comment: You also should also give us example data whats in the tables.

Comment: @RaymondNijland please see the updated question. I added example JSON for each table. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I am not good with PostgreSQL. Probably made wrong assumptions and code is probably not intended for production.

I almost sure you cannot just result a nested object. But you can receive JSON. So

```js
SELECT 
 json_build_object(
   'school_name', school_name,
   'people', (
    SELECT 
     json_agg(json_build_object(
      'profile_name', profile_name,
      'articles', (
       SELECT 
        json_agg(json_build_object(
         'article_name', article_name
        ))
       FROM tb_article
       WHERE profile_id = tb_profile.facid
      ) 
     ))
    FROM tb_profile
    WHERE school_id = tb_school.id
   )
 ) AS result
FROM tb_school
```

it will give you row as JSON, which you can `JSON.parse`.

If you want to test you can use [this learning service](https://pgexercises.com/questions/basic/classify.html). I used it with this code.

```js
SELECT 
 json_build_object(
   'name', firstname,
   'slots', (
    SELECT 
     json_agg(json_build_object(
      'number', slots,
      'facility', (
       SELECT 
        json_agg(json_build_object(
         'name', name
        ))
       FROM cd.facilities
       WHERE facid = cd.bookings.facid
      ) 
     ))
    FROM cd.bookings
    WHERE memid = cd.members.memid
   )
 ) AS result
FROM cd.members
```

It probably will be helpful or provide more ideas.

Comment: Wow that is awesome! Thank you sooo much for the fast reply and all the effort. Was exactly what I was looking for!